# PHP / PDO : query request works, prepared request doesn't

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepare

I would like to user prepared request with PDO but it doesn't seem to return any result while the query request do return some.

Here, there are my two requests :

Prepared request :

```
$req = $this->bdd->prepare('SELECT u.id, u.username, hm.desc, s.name AS shop, hm.amount, hm.date FROM history_members AS hm LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = hm.user_id LEFT JOIN shops AS s ON s.id = hm.shop_id WHERE hm.user_id = :id');
$req->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$data = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$req->closeCursor();
```

Query request :

```
$req = $this->bdd->query('SELECT u.id, u.username, hm.desc, s.name AS shop, hm.amount, hm.date FROM history_members AS hm LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = hm.user_id LEFT JOIN shops AS s ON s.id = hm.shop_id WHERE hm.user_id = '.$id);
$data = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$req->closeCursor();
```

What am I doing wrong with the prepared request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not execute your query.
First execute query then fetch the result.

Comment: @itsols : I had to wait 10 minutes